# How to SSRS RDL report file in an aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I want to show SSRS report file rdl file in an aspx page. I build a `web application` and in the same solution i have created `Report server project` also now i want to show this report server project's rdl files in my web application .aspx page. How can I show this rdl file on the aspx page and how to pass parameters from aspx page to this rdl report?

I don't need to convert rdl into rdlc.

I am using VS2010 and sql server 2012 Reporting services.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't "need" (want?) to use an RDLC you'll need to set up the [ReportViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251771) for [Remote Processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252075.aspx). You'll need to have the report deployed and running on your report server, which you should probably be able to check through the web interface.